# AVX calculation precision

Tags: c++, avx, avx2, mandelbrot

I wrote a program to display the mandelbrot set. To speed it up, I used AVX (really AVX2) instructions through the `<immintrin.h>` header.
The problem is: The result of the AVX computation (with double precision) has artifacts, and it differs to the result when computed using "normal" doubles.
In detail, there is a function `getIterationCount` which calculates the number of iterations until the mandelbrot sequence exceeds 4, or assumes the point is included in the set if the sequences does not exceed 4 during the first N steps.
The code looks like this:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <complex>
#include <immintrin.h>

class MandelbrotSet {
public:
    int getIterationCount(const std::complex<double>, const int) const noexcept;
    __m256i getIterationCount(__m256d cReal, __m256d cIm, unsigned maxIterations) const noexcept;
};

inline int MandelbrotSet::getIterationCount(const std::complex<double> c, const int maxIterations) const noexcept
{
    double currentReal = 0;
    double currentIm = 0;
    double realSquare;
    double imSquare;
    for (int i = 0; i < maxIterations; ++i) {
        realSquare = currentReal * currentReal;
        imSquare = currentIm * currentIm;
        currentIm = 2 * currentReal * currentIm + c.imag();
        currentReal = realSquare - imSquare + c.real();
        if (realSquare + imSquare >= 4) {
            return i;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

const __m256i negone = _mm256_set_epi64x(-1, -1, -1, -1);
const __m256i one = _mm256_set_epi64x(1, 1, 1, 1);
const __m256d two = _mm256_set_pd(2, 2, 2, 2);
const __m256d four = _mm256_set_pd(4, 4, 4, 4);

//calculates for i = 0,1,2,3
//output[i] = if ctrl[i] == 0b11...1 then onTrue[i] else onFalse[i]
inline __m256i _mm256_select_si256(__m256i onTrue, __m256i onFalse, __m256i ctrl) {
    return _mm256_or_si256(_mm256_and_si256(onTrue, ctrl), _mm256_and_si256(onFalse, _mm256_xor_si256(negone, ctrl)));
}

inline __m256i MandelbrotSet::getIterationCount(__m256d cReal, __m256d cIm, unsigned maxIterations) const noexcept {
    __m256i result = _mm256_set_epi64x(0, 0, 0, 0);
    __m256d currentReal = _mm256_set_pd(0, 0, 0, 0);
    __m256d currentIm = _mm256_set_pd(0, 0, 0, 0);
    __m256d realSquare;
    __m256d imSquare;
    for (unsigned i = 0; i <= maxIterations; ++i)
    {
        realSquare = _mm256_mul_pd(currentReal, currentReal);
        imSquare = _mm256_mul_pd(currentIm, currentIm);

        currentIm = _mm256_mul_pd(currentIm, two);
        currentIm = _mm256_fmadd_pd(currentIm, currentReal, cIm);

        currentReal = _mm256_sub_pd(realSquare, imSquare);
        currentReal = _mm256_add_pd(currentReal, cReal);

        __m256i isSmaller = _mm256_castpd_si256(_mm256_cmp_pd(_mm256_add_pd(realSquare, imSquare), four, _CMP_LE_OS));
        result = _mm256_select_si256(_mm256_add_epi64(one, result), result, isSmaller);

        //if (i % 10 == 0 && !isSmaller.m256i_i64[0] && !isSmaller.m256i_i64[1] && !isSmaller.m256i_i64[2] && !isSmaller.m256i_i64[3]) return result;
    }
    return result;
}

using namespace std;

int main() {
    MandelbrotSet m;
    std::complex<double> point(-0.14203954214360026, 1);

    __m256i result_avx = m.getIterationCount(_mm256_set_pd(-0.14203954214360026, -0.13995837669094691, -0.13787721123829355, -0.13579604578563975),
        _mm256_set_pd(1, 1, 1, 1), 2681);

    int result_normal = m.getIterationCount(point, 2681);
    cout << "Normal: " << result_normal << ", AVX: " << result_avx.m256i_i64[0] << ", at point " << point << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

When I run this code, I get the following result:
(The point -0.14203954214360026 + i is chosen intentionally, because both methods return the same/almost the same value in most points)

```
Normal: 13, AVX: 20, at point (-0.14204,1)
```

A difference of 1 might be acceptable, but a difference of 7 seems quite big, since both methods use double precision.
Have AVX instructions a lower precision than "normal" instruction? If not, why do both results differ so much?
I use MS Visual Studio 2017, MS Visual C++ 2017 15.6 v14.13 141 and my computer has a i7-7700K Processor. The Project is compiled for x64. The result is the same if it is compiler with no or full optimization.
The rendered results look like this:
AVX:
[image: AVX]
Normal
[image: Normal]

The values of `realSquare` and `imSquare` during the loop are as follows:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 0.0201752, 1
2, 1.25858, 0.512543
3, 0.364813, 0.367639
4, 0.0209861, 0.0715851
5, 0.0371096, 0.850972
6, 0.913748, 0.415495
7, 0.126888, 0.0539759
8, 0.00477863, 0.696364
9, 0.69493, 0.782567
10, 0.0527514, 0.225526
11, 0.0991077, 1.48388
12, 2.33115, 0.0542994
13, 4.5574, 0.0831971
```

In the AVX loop the values are:

```
0, 0, 0
1, 0.0184406, 1
2, 1.24848, 0.530578
3, 0.338851, 0.394109
4, 0.0365017, 0.0724287
5, 0.0294888, 0.804905
6, 0.830307, 0.478687
7, 0.04658, 0.0680608
8, 0.024736, 0.78746
9, 0.807339, 0.519651
10, 0.0230712, 0.0872787
11, 0.0400014, 0.828561
12, 0.854433, 0.404359
13, 0.0987707, 0.0308286
14, 0.00460416, 0.791455
15, 0.851277, 0.773114
16, 0.00332154, 0.387519
17, 0.270393, 1.14866
18, 1.02832, 0.0131355
19, 0.773319, 1.51892
20, 0.776852, 10.0336
```

Comment: Is your non-AVX math done in 32-bit code using x87, with 80-bit internal precision?  If not, then it's done with the scalar version of the same AVX instructions you're using, e.g. `vmulsd` instead of `vmulpd`, which uses IEEE754 64-bit `double`, including subnormal support.  *What compiler and options are you using?*

Comment: Did you try using `fma()` in your scalar loop, to match the FP operations you're doing in the vector loop?  I forget if MSVC fuses `x*y + z` into an FMA, or if that depends on it's equivalent of `-ffast-math`.  (I think from `"stdafx.h"` that you're on MSVC, but that doesn't tell me if you're making a 32-bit executable with x87 scalar math.)  Related: https://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/03/21/intermediate-floating-point-precision/ about intermediate FP precision and how older MSVC did weird things to reduce the x87 precision.

Comment: @PeterCordes: I edited the question to include the information. Additionally, the disassembly uses `mulsd` for multiplication. Using `fma()` does not make a difference, even though the scalar part did not compile to fma instructions.

Comment: don't put images on dropbox. upload to stack.imgur.com and show them inline instead

Comment: Unrelated code review: don't put vector constants at global scope or make them static, like `const __m256i one = _mm256_set1_epi64x(1);`.  Compilers actually do *worse* with that than defining them inside functions.  (They init the static storage at runtime by copying from another vector constant.)  Also, you don't need `_mm256_select_si256`.  Instead use the `vcmpps` result *as a 0 / -1 integer*.  i.e. `result = _mm256_sub_epi64(result,  _mm256_castpd_si256(cmp_result))`.  x - (-1) is `x++`, and `x - (0)` is `x`.  Also, use `set1(2) instead of `set(2,2,2,2)`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reversing the order of the arguments passed to `_mm256_set_pd` solves the problem.

If you inspect the value of `cReal` in the debugger you'll see that the first element is set to `-0.13579604578563975` not `-0.14203954214360026`.

Comment: Or use `_mm256_setr_pd(0,1,2,3)` instead of `_mm256_set_pd(3,2,1,0)`, if you prefer writing vectors in the same order as array initializers, instead of in Intel's normal order that makes left shifts go left.

Comment: Thanks, I'm sorry. I have debugged it so often and overlooked this.